# declaring a class member function as friend of a template class

Tags: c++

```
#include< iostream>  
using namespace std;  

template< class t>  
class X  
{  
  private:  
      t x;    

  public:  
        template< class u>  
         friend u y::getx(X< u> ); 

      void setx(t s)  
      {x=s;}  
           };      

class y   
{  
 public:  
     template< class t>  
     t getx(X< t> d)  
     {return d.x;}     
};  

int main()  
{  
    X< int> x1;  
    x1.setx(7);  
    y y1;  
    cout<< y1.getx(x1);    
    return 0;  
}
```

The above program, when compiled, showed an error that `y` is neither a function nor a member function, so it cannot be declared a friend. What is the way to include `getx` as a friend in `X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should "forward declare" class y before template class X. I.e., just put:

class y; // forward declaration

template
class X...

Answer (score 2):

You have to arrange the classes so that the function declared as a friend is actually visible before class X. You also have to make X visible before y...

```
template< class t>  
class X;

class y   
{  
 public:  
     template< class t>  
     t getx(X< t> d)  
     {return d.x;}     
};

template< class t>  
class X  
{  
  private:  
      t x;    

  public:  
        template< class u>  
         friend u y::getx(X< u> ); 

      void setx(t s)  
      {x=s;}  
};
```

Comment: but i already defined entire class x before class y....is forward declaration necessary....what does it do

Comment: @avinash - To be able to make a function a friend, that function must be visible, which means that class y has to be visible, as the function is a member. And when declaring that member function, class X has to be visible there as it is a parameter. The forward declaration says that X is a class template, which is enough at that point.